# How would I solve the following question on continuity?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity, piecewise-continuity

[image]

"Find m such that the following function is continuous from -infinity to +infinity"

I know the conditions for continuity but I am not sure how I would apply it to the piecewise function and the unknown.

Any help?

Comment: Think about where there might be a problem and what you might to to eliminate it. What do you know about the continuity of the pieces?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Evaluate the two pieces at $x=-2$, set them equal to each other, and solve for $m$.

Answer (score 0):

We can utilize one of the requirements for continuity.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to-2}(f(x))=f(-2)$$
The left-side and right-side limits must be equal in order for the ordinary limit to exist. Remember that $x\to-2^-$ means $x\lt-2$. We can use direct substitution in the first branch.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to-2^-}(f(x))=m(-2)-5=f(-2)$$
We can now solve for $m$.
\begin{align}
-2m-5&=(-2)^2+6(-2)-3\\
-2m&=4-12-3+5\\
-2m&=-6\\
m&=3
\end{align}
The function is continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$ with $m=3$.